# PHP Fatal error: Class 'Inflector' not found

Tags: php, linux, cakephp, centos, cakephp-2.1

I tried to run a PHP file (of cakePHP) by the following

```
 $ /bin/sh /var/www/html/app/Console/cake HumanResource UpdateData
```

But there is an error occur:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Inflector' not found in /var/www/html/app/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php on line 209
```

Some information in my server:

- Centos: 6.5
- PHP: 5.3
- Httpd: 2.2.15
- CakePHP version: 2.1.3

Please help me to fix it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You forgot add:

```
use Cake\Utility\Inflector;
```

Example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Shell;

use Cake\Console\Shell;
use Cake\Utility\Inflector;

class CamerasShell extends Shell {
    public function main() {
        $this->out(Inflector::slug('Please Generate Me Slug', '-'));
    }
}
```

Comment: This is for CakePHP 3.x. CakePHP 2.x doesn't work this way (doesn't support namespaces).